# Missing data LSSVM

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, missing-data

how to deal with missing data in least square support vector machine ( LSSVM )?

I am using matlab I am pretty new in machine learning and I use the breast cancer database (from UCI repository) there is missing data (?) how to deal with this in classfication problem using  LSSVM( least square support vector machine).